# Python: How to put multiple and/or conditionals in an if statement?

Tags: python, arrays, conditional-statements

I'm new to python and thought this was somewhat simple, but am running into some problems here. I'm trying to put multiple conditionals in an if statement. The part of the code I'm trying to do this to looks like this:

```
if (pp_or_bi < 0.5 and (ppar > 0 or ppar < 0) and (bpar > 0 or bpar < 0)):
    tab.append(ppar[pele + 10*psel])
else:
    tab.append(bipar[bele + 8*bint])
```

What's going on here: ppar or bipar contains some values, and the stuff within the brackets [ ] is picking a certain number (with a certain index) of ppar or bipar to append into tab.

Because of the way I'm updating things, if an element of ppar or bipar is 0, I get a divide by zero error and can't proceed.

Therefore, what I'm trying to do is when I get down to this if conditional, it needs to meet the condition that whatever element in ppar or bipar I'm looking at is not zero (if it is zero, I would not append it to list tab).

I've tried searching around for what the syntax should be but it seems like it could also be a problem with putting an array in my if statement. This syntax I currently have doesn't work. I'd really appreciate any help/suggestions on how to do this. Thanks!

EDIT: Is there a way to do this conditional such that you can say that two consecutive values of ppar or bpar are not equal to each other? So something like when you go through the statement once and get a value, and then go through it again and get the same value, it won't go through the if statement and append to tab.

Comment: can you show us an example of the contents of bpar & ppar?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] with an [edit] to the question

Comment: Because `ppar` and `bpar` are arrays it is not clear what condition you are testing. For example `ppbar != 0` will give a boolean array. Do you want to test if any elements are not equal to zero or all elements? Instead of `ppbar != 0` use something like `(ppbar != 0).any()` or `(ppbar != 0).all()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are doing is checking if ppar or bipar is 0 couldn't the following work?

```
if (pp_or_bi < 0.5 and ppar!=0 and bpar!=0 ):
    tab.append(ppar[pele + 10*psel])
else:
    tab.append(bipar[bele + 8*bint])
```

Comment: That's what I tried initially, but that didn't work.

Comment: Are ppar and bpar integers?

Comment: They are arrays that hold elements.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are comparing the array, and not whats in them. you are doing ppar!=0 when you should be doing ppar[_element_]!=0

Comment: Ah I tried that too, but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you divide by 0, you will have a `ZeroDivisionError`. You can catch this error with a `try` statement like this:

```
try:    
    if pp_or_bi < 0.5:
        tab.append(ppar[pele + 10*psel])
    else:
        tab.append(bipar[bele + 8*bint])
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
```

If `ppar` and `bpar` are lists that contain a few values that are equal to 0, this may be the best solution. Otherwise, it would be better to use a different solution, as suggested by the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If ppar and bpar are lists and you want to ensure that its particular element is non-zero before appending it to 'tab'. Then you can put an extra check and do something along this line:

```
if (pp_or_bi < 0.5):
    if (ppar[pele + 10*psel] != 0 ):
        tab.append(ppar[pele + 10*psel])
else:
    if (bipar[bele + 10*bint] != 0 ):  
        tab.append(bipar[bele + 8*bint])
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code:

```
pp_or_bi = 0.1
ppar = 2
bpar = 3
tab = []

if (pp_or_bi < 0.5 and (ppar > 0 or ppar < 0) and (bpar > 0 or bpar < 0)):
    print('first worked')
else:
    print('second worked')
```

and it worked fine. By changing the values I got the appropriate outcome. what is wrong with your code?